# How OAuth2 server issue expierd token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I can not understand, what MUST `OAuth2 server` do with expired token? For example `client` have expired access token and starts `auth code`, `password` or `client credetials` grant flow, auth server check request and ??? (delete expired and issue new access token, such as in `refresh` flow?)

Answer (score 0):

An "OAuth2 server" could mean different things. It could be a "resource server" which consumes a token, or the "authorization server" which issues tokens. Remember these could be completely separate.

What should a resource server do with an expired token? It should reject it of course and send an error response to the client. See [section 7 of the OAuth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-7).

If you mean what should the authorization server "do" with an expired token, then I'd guess you're referring to token storage? None of this is defined by the OAuth2 spec. It's possible the server might not even retain copies of the tokens (they could be signed JWTs, for example). There's generally no need to retain expired tokens, and there's no specified connection with what happens when the client initiates a new flow to obtain a new token. It might make sense to expire existing *unexpired* tokens for that client and resource owner when a new token is issued though.

Comment: thanks. You understand me correctly about "authorization server". I don't find this in specification, so i can issue new token on every auth flow, and forget all expired bearer tokens? i can't expire unexpired tokens, because `resource owner` can use `client` on defferent platforms/browsers.

Comment: Yes, you can forget about expired tokens. Not sure what you mean about expiring tokens and the user/resource owner. None of the flows you mention should be affected by the platform or browser they are using. The access token is only used by the client which is a separate application. If the authorization server stores the tokens it can expire a token whenever it chooses and if the resource server has some way of checking the token with the authorization server (not defined in the spec, but generally the case), then it will know the token is expired.